# Java: ArraryList, how to count the number of elements with the same instance variable?

Tags: java, arraylist, count

Context: trying to write a programme that will store music albums.

So I have created an object called 'Album', the default constructor is as follows:

```
public Album(String artist, String title, int trackCount){
    this.artist = artist;
    this.title = title;
    this trackCount = trackCount
    status = null
}
```

The variable `status` refers to 3 possible statuses:

AVAILABLE; BROKEN; MISSING.

I then made an arraylist:

```
...
public class AlbumList(){
    albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
}
```

I know that the `.size()` method will return the number of elements in my list.

However I am unsure how I would find the number of albums in my list that are missing.

I was thinking I should create a variable, say int `missingAlbums`, then from this maybe use an if statement to go through the array and increment `missingAlbums` each time an album is found with a status MISSING. Though I am not entirely sure how to do this.

Here is the code I have:

```
public int numberOfMissingAlbums(){
    missingAlbums= 0;
    for(Album missingRecord: AlbumList){
        if(missingRecord.status.equals("MISSING")){
            missingAlbums++;
        }
    }
    return missingAlbums;
}
```

I am getting an error saying '.equals on incompatible types', and I have no idea what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Just try doing it, and get back here with the code you tried if you have a concrete question.

Comment: Sidebar question: Wouldn't it be better to have a `List` of missing albums instead of just the count? You can then use `List.size()` to get the count from there. 2 birds with 1 stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose using a method that will return a `List` of missing albums:

```
public static List<Album> getMissingAlbums(List<Album> currentAlbums) {
    List<Album> missingAlbums = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Album currAlbum : currentAlbums) {
        if (currAlbum.status.equals("MISSING")) {
            missingAlbums.add(currAlbum);
        }
    }

    return missingAlbums;
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
    List<Album> missingAlbums = getMissingAlbums(albumList);
```

And get the count with `List.size()` like so:

```
    int missingAlbumCount = missingAlbums.size();
```

Now you have both the albums that are missing, and the count of albums that are missing.

Comment: Thanks! Though I am getting an error saying '.equals on incompatible types', and I have no idea what the problem is. Any ideas as to why this could be an issue?

Comment: @Maitiu is your `status` a `String`? It should work if it is.

Comment: @Maitiu, if you have a `String getStatus()` method, you could use that instead. So it should look like `if (currAlbum.getStatus().equals("MISSING")) {`

Comment: `status` is of type `albumStatus`, which is an `enum`

Comment: @Maitiu, you could do this then: `if (currAlbum.status == Album.albumStatus.MISSING) {`

Comment: this didn't quite work, however `if (currAlbum.status == AlbumStatus.MISSING) {` is coming up with no warnings or errors, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Maitiu, awesome. Glad to hear!

Answer (score 8):

Just iterate over the elements and check if the album is missing. If so, increment missingAlbums.

If you are using Java 8, you can also use streams like this: `missingAlbums = albumList.stream().filter(album -> album.getStatus() == MISSING).count()`

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < albumList.size; i++) {
        if (albumList.get(i).equals("MISSING")) {
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of missing tracks is something that is going to need to be calculated repeatedly, it might be a better choice to make a wrapper class around the arraylist that also stores the number of missing albums. This would let you increment that number if a missing album was added to the list instead of having to iterate over the list every time.

Something like this:

```
public class Albums {

    List<Album> albums;
    int missing;

    public Albums() {
        albums = new ArrayList<>();
        missing = 0;
    }

    public void add(Album album) {
        albums.add(album);
        if (albums.getStatus().equals("MISSING")  {
            missing++;
        }
    }

    public int getMissingAlbums() {
        return missing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate every element and get the object and find the status if it is `MISSING` then increment it

```
int missingAlbums = 0;
albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
Iterator itr = albumList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Album temp = (Album)itr.next();
    if(temp.status.equals("MISSING"))
    missingAlbums++;
}
System.out.println(missingAlbums);
```

OR using for each loop

```
int missingAlbums= 0;
albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
for(Album temp : albumList ){
    if(temp.status.equals("MISSING"))
    missingAlbums++;
}
System.out.println(missingAlbums);
```